# SQL Query, how to omit specific data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL Query that returns a list of Cost Center's that are closed. This is known by a 'C' in the TE_INACTIVE Column.

The issue: Some Cost Centers were moved to a different company, so there is a duplicate of 3 cost centers that are both closed and open. Since this cost center was closed and re-opened, I do not want to read it in anymore since the new one doesn't have a 'C'. How can I do this?

In other words, if one of the duplicate Cost Center's doesn't have a 'C' in it, then I want to skip it.

Here is (part of) my original query and a screenshot of what I mean.

```
select distinct TE_COST_CENTER, TE_INACTIVE from ABCS_TABLE_E where 
TE_COST_CENTER = '38M'
```

[Click this to view picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfuoh.png)

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: What does *`moved to a different company`* mean in terms of your table?

Comment: Not to be snarky, but have you heard of the "AND" keyword?  I think that's what you're looking for: `...and te_inactive <> 'C'`

Comment: @Ferdinand Gaspar
So I have a picture uploaded if you click on "enter image description here" should probably update that.

Comment: @ PM 77-1 Moved to a different company meaning, each of the rows has a company code associated, so the duplicate represents the new cost center for the new company that it is now a part of. I was told not to use the company code to distinguish between the two. That I only need to update that one line.

Comment: `select distinct TE_COST_CENTER, TE_INACTIVE from ABCS_TABLE_E where TE_COST_CENTER = '38M' AND TE_INACTIVE <> 'C'`  <>  meaning not equal  as @theGleep suggested.

Comment: @KeyurVaidya It's sample, edit your question, add sample data and desired outputs, then you will get answers, that's the best explanation for who read your question.

Comment: @theGleep I understand where you're coming from, so here's the thing. Each of the cost center is either closed ('C') or open (no 'C'). There's only two options, so if I did and <> 'C' then it'd return every single Cost Center, which is accomplishing nothing. Thanks though!

Comment: Oh!  So if one of them has 'C', you don't want to see either of them?  Subqueries to the rescue!  @p1erstef has it.

Comment: @theGleep exactly yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the "NOT EXISTS" operator:

```
select distinct TE_COST_CENTER, TE_INACTIVE from ABCS_TABLE_E t1
where TE_INACTIVE = 'C'
and not exists (select * from ABCS_TABLE_E t2 where t2.TE_COST_CENTER = t1.TE_COST_CENTER and t2.TE_INACTIVE <>'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT TE_COST_CENTER, TE_INACTIVE
FROM ABCS_TABLE_E
WHERE TE_CO NOT IN (SELECT TE_CO FROM ABCS_TABLE_E WHERE TE_INACTIVE = 'C');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use sub-query to select those cost centers that has been closed 'C'. any records of that cost center will not be select.

```
SELECT TE_COST_CENTER, 
       TE_INACTIVE
  FROM ABCS_TABLE_E
 WHERE TE_COST_CENTER NOT IN (SELECT TE_COST_CENTER
                                FROM ABCS_TABLE_E
                               WHERE TE_INACTIVE = 'C')
```